# 2D game - how AI enemy knows that there is a barrier between them and player

Tags: c++, geometry, 2d, line, collision

I have the enemy at position x1,y1 and the player at x2,y2. For the houses (the barriers) I use the collision circles, e.g. x3,y3,r.

How can I check that enemy sees player and is able to aim and fire? So, I am looking for algoritm for test that line x1,y1-x2,y2 touches the circle or not.

Thank you for your advice! :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please, read [ask].
Have you at least tried Googling `line circle intersection`? It yields a ton of results for me.

Comment: @ProXicT [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). I can speak from personal experience that trying to google stuff like this usually gets me directed to the Is-This-Even-Written-In-A-Language-That-Exists-On-Earth sites like the math-heavy side of Wikipedia or Wolfram Alpha, which are next-to-useless for anyone who isn't actively working on a degree in formal mathematics. If there's already a question here dealing with this issue, we can tag it as a duplicate; if not, I think there's enough information to answer it.

Comment: @Xirema Usually, when someone is trying to write a game engine of some sort, they need to learn at least some math and they will definitely come across sites which are math-heavy. But I see your point and because I very well remember being in OP's shoes, I'll try to write up an answer for him.

Comment: The other downside of googling when you don't really know what you are looking for is [Sturgeon's Revelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law). Since the Internet is approximately 90% crud, we can infer that the vast majority of tutorials and code samples one finds will be crud. You already have to have some idea of what you need in order to distinguish the good information from the stuff that'll lead you down rabbit holes or make you a worse programmer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic line-circle intersection algorithm based on a simple trigonometry:

```
bool lineCircleIntersection(const Line& line, const Circle& circle) {
      const float dx = line.end.x - line.start.x;
      const float dy = line.end.y - line.start.y;
      const float a = dx * dx + dy * dy;
      const float b = 2 * (dx * (line.start.x - circle.origin.x) + dy * (line.start.y - circle.origin.y));
      float c = circle.origin.x * circle.origin.x + circle.origin.y * circle.origin.y;
      c += line.start.x * line.start.x + line.start.y * line.start.y;
      c -= 2 * (circle.origin.x * line.start.x + circle.origin.y * line.start.y);
      c -= circle.radius * circle.radius;
      return (b * b - 4 * a * c) >= 0;
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63aa7a25af7aa757)